# ruby - How to send a parameter from a nested rails form to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nested form in Rails, with the deepest partials are like that:

```
<%= f.fields_for :character_traits do |attr_f| %>
  <% if attr_f.object.field_name == field %>
    <%= attr_f.number_field :field_value, :disabled => (true if action_name == "show"), data: {toggle: 'popover', title: attr_f.object.field_name, content: description_for_trait(attr_f.object) }, class: :numb %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This code allows me to use Bootstrap popovers, but I want to add and modify these descriptions (which are kept in the `descriptions` table and are extracted via a helper method `description_for_trait(attr_f.object)`) dynamically, which brought me to jQuery.

I added https://github.com/wrdieter/jquery_context_menu-rails and defined a menu, which successfully add an entry into the `descriptions` table. In `application.js` I wrote:

```
//= require jquery.contextMenu.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.has-tooltip').tooltip();
  $('*').popover({
    trigger: 'click'
  });

$.contextMenu({
            selector: '.numb', 
            callback: function(key, options) {
              if(key = "edit") {
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "/descriptions",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: { description:{character_trait_id: 9303, trait_desc: 'This is my meeey'}}
                  }
                )
              }
              else {
                alert("Not implemented yet..."); 
              }
            },
            items: {
                "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
                "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
               copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
                "sep1": "---------",
                "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                    return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
                }}
            }
        });

        $('.numb').on('click', function(e){
            console.log('clicked', this);
        })
});
```

This allows me to add an entry into a `descriptions` table, which is

```
  create_table "descriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "character_trait_id"
    t.text     "trait_desc"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  end
```

But I have encountered a problem. I need to know the `id` if a trait I want to add description for. Now I just hardcoded these ids in my jQuery function, but I must to get them somehow dynamically. In Rails I can get these ids like that:

```
attr_f.object.id
```

But how can I get this `id` in jQuery? Maybe, if it is impossible, I can send the `id` somehow?

Comment: What is the element which fires the event?, do this `if(key = "edit") {...}` work well?

Comment: so what you are looking for is the parent ID when the jquery has the nested form elements?

Comment: Sebastian, the event's trigger is a click on the one of the menu's items. Yes, all the code I provided works well, and the entries with `id` 9303 and the text I hardcoded add properly. The point is: I don't know how to replace this 9303 with `id` from the rails form...

Comment: The context menu opens with a right click on a nested number_field (one of the standart tags).

Comment: Michael, sorry, I don't get you. Is there some way to call `attr_f.object.id` in jQuery menu?

Comment: You can try adding a `data-id` with the `id` you need to the element that will be clicked, and then you can get that value like `$(this).data('id')`.